# How to make https request from google app engine(python 2.7) to facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, python-2.7, urllib2

```
profile=urllib2.urlopen("https://www.graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me?access_token="+access_token)
```

In this code error=

> 'An error occured while connecting to the server: %s' % e) error: An
>   error occured while connecting to the server: DNS lookup failed for
>   URL:
>   https://www.graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBALIUnSI0kzOCoom0ole1kGNsPsZA9lSaxZAxOz56wHJTUhoG1a3zC7kRH3BrWcL5XtZAjzrUCVesgE6tqOOiAzMeS2JGEtcL51pgQJ697n96YogVE9wVhoiGs9uN40Y7XDRRM60ZCYHC1gJF9I6stTDFZBoKE0KEMc3RFYPRrPzUM264BIZD

Answer (score 0):

You have added an extra **www.** to the URL

The code should look like this:

```
profile=urllib2.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me?access_token="+access_token)
```

Comment: After this it is giving:raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Comment: Your python code is probably good, if you paste this into your browser you get "malformed access token" (from the graph api): https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBALIUnSI0kzOCoom0ole1kGNsPsZA9lSaxZAxOz56wHJTUhoG1a3zC7kRH3BrWcL5XtZAjzrUCVesgE6tqOOiAzMeS2JGEtcL51pgQJ697n96YogVE9wVhoiGs9uN40Y7XDRRM60ZCYHC1gJF9I6stTDFZBoKE0KEMc3RFYPRrPzUM264BIZD

Comment: no i just changed the access token for privacy thats why it is showing malformed...